# Is there an option for a "Confirmation Dialog" box?

Tags: cognito-forms

I was wondering whether Cognito Forms had the option to pop-up with a confirmation dialog box after the submit button is pressed just to let the user double check for any mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

I am a developer with Cognito Forms. We do not have an option for a confirmation dialog; however, you could use a multi-page form and make the last page your confirmation page. You can build the confirmation page using our content field, which allows you to reference other fields on the form.

[image]